How do you tell someone to offer something to everyone in a room by taking it physically to everyone in the room so everyone can have it?
Imagine you have guests, and you want to serve small chocolates in a box, and you give the box to a child, but you want to say it is to be given out to everyone and that you want him take the box to each person, so everyone can have at least one. The same situation is also applicable to other things like napkins/cologne/wet wipes to help guests clean their hands.
So, how do you say this in a idiomatic way. I have thought of some sentences, but I am not sure if they sound natural English. Here they are:
1- Serve it (around). (I am not sure whether this also applies to non-food offerings)
2- Give it to everyone.
3- Distribute (it).
4- Offer it to everyone.
5- Take it to everyone.
6- Hand it out.

A single chocolate can be substituted with "it"  but a box of chocolates needs "them"  e.g. "Offer them [the chocolates] to everyone"

@Mari-LouA - I can easily imagine offering it (the opened box) around.

After the business of the evening had been transacted Harry passed a box of cigars around and every city dad took a smoke. (1908 US newspaper)

@MichaelHarvey I read: passed a box of cigars, not passed it around. Anyway, some smart-arsed person would have told me that the child wasn't passing/handing out "a box" but the chocolates inside the box. The child would be carrying the box and the guests would be helping themselves. Between friends: "Pass me the chocolates" or in a novel perhaps "Offer a bonbon to the Grand-duchess of Witherspoon, will you dear?"

@Mari-LouA - I don't think there's a thin chocolate's thickness between handing round 'it' (a box/tray/platter/etc of chocolates) and handing 'them' around. I suppose you might reach a logical problem with 'them' at the point where there's only one left. (Do you have 'After Eight' chocolate mints where you are?)

I think they are all missing the core of what would make them idiomatic: "Please".

"Share" is also an word to use in many cases.

"Offer these around to everyone." This leaves no room for misinterpretation, even by a child.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica, True.  Without "please", all options suggested so far are in the command voice - and is presumptuous to use to a child or adult guest.

"him TO take"...

We very often say 'hand them round (or around)'. Other verbs that we might use include 'pass', 'offer', and 'take'.

Definition of hand round phrasal verb from the Oxford Advanced
Learner's Dictionary
hand round phrasal verb
hand something around
(also hand something round especially in British English)
​to offer or pass something, especially food or drinks, to all the
people in a group


Do you just say "Offer." or "Offer it."?

Not "it" but "this".    Offer this to our guests.or Offer our guests a chocolate.

Or as implied by the definition, Pass them round/out.

As an American, I'd understand "hand them around", but I'd say "hand them out", "pass them around" or "offer it to everyone".

As an adjective, it's common to refer to "hand passed hors d'oeuvres" to indicate that they are carried on trays by servers and offered individually to guests, although you wouldn't normally see "hand pass" as a phrasal verb in this context.

@Karen "hand them out" to these British ears would mean that everyone is expected to take one, rather than everyone having the option to have one.  So more appropriate for class worksheets than chocolates

To my (American) ear, here's how each option sounds:

"Serve [thing]" -- I would only use "serve" with food, and usually only with part of a meal, not a snack or candy or something. (I would understand you if you said "serve [thing] around", but I wouldn't say it; the word 'around' doesn't sound very natural to me here.)

"Give [] to everyone." -- The general idea is fine, although "give" rather than "offer" suggests you don't expect people to refuse.

"Give it/this to everyone." -- The singular sounds wrong to me here, if you're passing out a bunch of small objects.

"Give these to everyone." -- This would be fine, I think. (Technically it sounds like you mean "give all of these to everyone", but people would understand what you meant.)

"Give everybody one of these." -- This is more precise.

"Give each person one of these." -- This is the most precise, and might be good if you were saying it to a small child, and wanted to be very clear; it sounds a bit too formal otherwise.


When you say "give", it suggests that people aren't really expected to refuse. For something optional, like chocolates, you should say "offer" instead of "give". If you were providing guests with napkins at a dinner table, you would probably say "give"; technically people could refuse them, but you expect almost everybody will take one.
The use of "offer" instead of "give" does change the phrasing a little. "Give these to everyone" sounds slightly weird, as discussed above, but "offer these to everyone" sounds totally normal; you might only "give" someone a single chocolate from the container, but you can "offer" them the entire container (by presenting it to them, with the implication that they will only take one chocolate from it, or a reasonable amount.) You could also say "offer this to everyone", the same way (meaning the container), although I would still use the plural.

"Give/hand/pass these out [to everyone]." -- These ("give out [thing] / hand out [thing] / pass out [thing]") are all verbs that mean "distribute [thing]". (You can put the "[thing]" either before or after the word "out", although usually one will sound more natural than the other.)
"Pass these out." -- I'm only used to hearing this in school, or at work, or similar; it means "distribute exactly one of these to each person in the group." Normally used for something like paper notes at a meeting, or exams or assignments in school.
"Give these out." -- Sounds the same to me as "Give everybody one of these" or similar options. If you add "to everyone", it means what it sounds like (not suitable for optional chocolates, but appropriate for napkins.)
"Hand these out." -- Somewhere in between the previous two options.

All of these options sound fairly impersonal to me. "Pass these out" most of all, then "hand these out", then "give these out". They tend to be used when there are a lot of recipients. If your child is having a birthday party, and you're having them give exactly one little bag of candy to each person attending, you would use one of these verbs ("pass out" / "hand out" / "give out"). But if you were having a small dinner party, and wanted your child to offer a box of nice chocolates to a few adults in attendance, I think you would not say it that way.

"Distribute these." -- means the same as "give/hand/pass out", but I wouldn't use it at all in one of these situations; it's even more impersonal/formal/stilted, compared with the other options.


Thanks for the detailed answer. I appreciate it.

Your American ear hears very similarly to mine.  To be a little more explicit, though, my choice among these would be "offer them to everyone" or something closely related to that, such as "offer one to each person".  Even so, that only presumes, at best, that the offers will be made by physically carrying the items to each person.  That mode of offering might follow from context and custom under the circumstances, but I don't think there is any conventional phrase conveying that idea without saying it outright.

For some reason, I find “pass/hand/give these out” jarring – I think it’s the demonstrative pronoun as object that does it somehow. “Pass/hand out these bags of candy [to everyone]” sounds perfectly fine, as does “Pass/hand them out [to everyone]”. Give works better outside the imperative to me (“He was giving out bags of candy” is fine, but “Give out bags of candy” is odd). I could imagine “Pass these out” from a teacher instructing a student to distribute something to the class, but not from a parent instructing a kid to offer guests something. “Pass these around” works fine, though.

Share X out, hand X out, share X around, pass X around (et cetera) are all perfectly acceptable.
"Share them with everyone", "share them with your friends", or a more explicit "offer one to everyone" may be better when talking to a child.
There is also a convention of saying "take one and pass (it/them) on", so that each person passes the (e.g.) box of chocolates to the nearest person until everyone gets their chocolate.
